# How can you make Google VR View responsive?

Tags: javascript, google-vr

How can you make [Google VR View](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web) responsive?

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/mwLyvy

I've obviously set the the CSS width to 100%, but it doesn't crop as the screen becomes smaller than the view.

JavaScript

```
$( window ).on('load', function() {  
  $(".vrview").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('id');
    var src = $this.attr('data-src');
    var vrView = new VRView.Player('#' + id, {
      image: src,
      is_stereo: false,
      width: '100%',
      height: '400px'
    });
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.vrview{
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.

I don't think there are any setters like `setWidth(x)` or `set('width', x)` so I can't do anything like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  for(var v = 0; v < vrViews.length; v ++){
    var view = vrViews[v];
    view.set('width', 40);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you omit the width and height in the JavaScript you can then size the iFrame (not the .vrview container) via CSS.

Comment: I don't think that is the case... https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/ZJVxym?editors=0100

Comment: Literally you have to size the iframe directly. But you have manage proportions manually.
https://codepen.io/jshwlkr/full/XaoyyL/

Answer (score 0):

I actually had some joy with [embed responsively](http://embedresponsively.com/).

I created the standard code, made an iframe, then copied the iframe into embed responsively to get the following code:

```
<style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style>
<div class='embed-container'>
    <iframe allowfullscreen='true' scrolling='no' src='https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/index.html?image=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/5961/HY360_0103.jpg&is_stereo=false&' style='border: 0px;'></iframe>
</div>
```

Result:
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/Bdvrrw